# Restrict ability to Add Facebook Application to Peoples pages

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have set up a Facebook application that I need to prevent the general public from Adding to their pages as a tab.

The only way I can think of doing this is to set in place some logic that checks the page ID it's being loaded in to via FQL or likewise against a subset of Approved page IDs. If the ID of the page is not in our approved list, we display a "Access denied" page within the tab that is added to their page. While I believe this will work - it would require us to manually add a page ID to this list every time someone approved needs to add it to their page which isn't ideal.

Any help or better ideas would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Edit: reread your post, realized I misunderstood what you meant.

I think the best way to go about what you're after is a whitelist like you describe, although there are some steps you can take to reduce the number of people who find the application by accident, like disabling social discovery in the application settings and keeping all activity confined to that tab. Apart from that, you can't really sandbox it since you want the general public to be able to consume the app from your approved pages, so the whitelist is the best way to go.

---

The ability to add tabs to user profiles was [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/425/) in November:

> As we announced in August and again in October, we removed applications tabs from user profiles today. Users were notified of this change with inline messaging on tabs. Please note that this did not impact application tabs in Pages, which are fully supported.

Thus, you shouldn't have to worry about any users adding tabs to their profiles, as this functionality no longer exists.